# What Have I Done Wrong? | Python Code Not Running

Tags: python

Why python code dose not seem to want to run and i have tried everything on IDLE it says "RESTART" and then the file name and on PyCharm it said's "Process finished with exit code 0" so i have no idea what I've done wrong.

I would also like to add that if there is something stupid I've missed am sorry I've just started Python not to long ago and this is a starting project i wanted to make.

Help would be well appreciated.

```
import time
import os

def main_interface():
    print("Welcome to The Adventures!")
    print('''/nNew Game/nOptions/nExit''')
    loading_choose = input()
    loading_choose = loading_choose.lower()

    if loading_choose == 'New Game':
        new_game()

    elif loading_choose == 'Options':
        options()


def options():
    print("Welcome To Options")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\nGraphics\nAudio\nExit")
    options = input()
    options.lower()

    if options == 'Graphics':
        graphic_interface()

    elif options == 'Audio':
        audio_interface()

    elif options == 'Exit':
        main_interface()

def graphic_interface():
    print("What Graphics Would You Like?")
    print("\nLow\nMedium\nHigh")
    graphics = input()
    graphics = graphics.lower()

    if graphics == 'Low':
        print("Graphics Set To Low")
        options()

    elif graphics == 'Medium':
        print("Graphics Set To Medium")
        time.sleep(1)
        options()

    elif graphics == 'High':
        print("Graphics Set To High")
        time.sleep(1)
        options()

def audio_interface():
    print("What Do You Want Your Volume To Be?")
    print("0-100")
    volume = input()

    if volume <100:
        print("Volume Greater Then 100")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Try Again!")
        audio_interface()
    else:
        print("Volume Set To"+volume)
        options()
```

Comment: You never actually *do* anything. I assume at the end of the file you want to call `main_interface()` to kick things off? All you did was define some functions

Comment: See also: `if __name__ == "__main__"` as a python idiom for things to happen if the script is the primary script being invoked.

Comment: I would start with how you are prompting the user, and then look at how that raw input is being stored in `input()`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why IDLE/Pycharm is not doing anything is because your code isn't doing anything. What I mean is that no functions are being called by your program - it's just a bunch of functions.

To fix it, just call a function in your program (write this outside of a function).

It's a simple mistake to make, but it is completely understandable given that you beginning python.

But also, I see that there is no `new_game()` function defined, which you call in the `main_interface()` function. Also, in the `audio_interface()` function, the `input()` function is returning a `str` not an `int`, so you would want to convert the result to an `int` like so:

`volume = int(input())`

Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0):

add

```
main_interface()
```

to end of script to run function main_interface.

remove line `loading_choose = loading_choose.lower()`
because it turns input text to lowercase and it won't mach any option.

Comment: he should change it to `loading_choose.title()` this will capitalise the first letter which is what the options are..